# constructing valid CTL or LTL expression (in NuSMV)

Tags: logic, ctl, nusmv

I'm trying to create a valid CTL or LTL expression for model checking in NuSMV.

I have a variable in a game, with actors running around trying to catch each other.
Variable is, State_Of_Game : {Win,Lose,Playing}

and I want to express that from every starting state the game can be both won or lost.

So, how would I implement this in CTL or LTL?

I was thinking something like AG (S_O_G = Win | S_O_G = Lose) but don't know how to implement that it is seen from every starting state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the SMV notation, so I am guessing about this, but the key points are:

1. To avoid quantifying over all states at the outside: you don't want to say that all games can be either won or lost, but only the starting game.  So just have a formula at the starting state with no outermost modality
2. To use a conjunction, not disjunction: you want to assert both winnability and losability
3. You need separate modalities wrapping each of the branches: winnability, losability is an existential claim, saying it is possible to attain a condition.

I think the formula you need is: (EG SOG=Win) & (EG SOG=Lose) at the root, which might mean in something like an init/start clause, or asserting at a named root clause.  If SMV doesn't have the EG modality, you can translate into just AG using the equivalence EG p = !(AG !p), since the two are De Morgan duals.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this : AF(State_of_Game=Win| State_of_Game=Lose)

Comment: This would be verified even by an initial state s.t. every possible path leads only to a state in which the game is lost (i.e. there is no possible winning strategy). The question asks for a property that is verified if every initial state admits both a winning and a loosing strategy.